# Book about a pair of wizards in another world

Tags: story-identification, wizards

I read this book back in the early 90s. It was about a pair of wizards - the older mentor and younger student. In their world wizards are generally looked down upon and even have fewer rights than other citizens. They live in a kingdom that is more enlightened about such things and work for the local king. They perform mostly low magic - one of the spells I recall them using was "Look over there!" or some thing to that affect that caused people looking for them to look in another direction. I remember that they surmised that they could make stronger magic if they had a way to purify their ingredients better.

The younger wizard had illegitimate children with one of the kings daughters. I recall a scene where they converse with a "blood mages" that uses aggressive magic.

At the end of the book they have been summoned to earth, where there is no magic.

Does anyone know what story this is?

Comment: This sounds like _Sun-Cross_ by Barbara Hambly. That was an omnibus of _The Rainbow Abyss_ and _The Magicians of Night_.

Answer (score 5):

@Spencer is certainty correct, I recognized this immediately from your description.

It's [The Rainbow Abyss](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/176312.The_Rainbow_Abyss), by Barbara Hambly.

[image: Book cover for "The rainbow abyss by Barbara Hambly]

1. *In their world wizards are generally looked down upon and even have fewer rights than other citizens*
   **Check**
2. *They live in a kingdom that is more enlightened about such things and work for the local king*
   **Check** (The local ruler is more
   enlightened, but his people, not so much)
3. *They perform mostly low magic - one of the spells I recall them using was "Look over there!"*
   **Check** "Who me?" & "Look over there!" are about the strongest survival spells they have.
4. *I remember that they surmised that they could make stronger magic if they had a way to purify their ingredients better*
   **Check**
5. *The younger wizard had illegitimate children with one of the kings daughters*
   Mostly **Check** from memory I know the younger had
   children, but can't remember with whom.
6. *At the end of the book they have been summoned to earth, where there is no magic*
   **Check** The younger travels through epynomous
   the "Rainbow Abyss" and finds himself on our Earth.

If you liked it you really should checkout the second book in the series [Magicians of the night](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/176301.The_Magicians_of_Night)